# Permutation matrix for $(13)(12)(23)(34)$?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations

for some reason I'm having a lot of trouble getting the correct Permutation matrix to the amalgamation of transpositions: $(13)(12)(23)(34)$

I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be:

\begin{bmatrix}
 0&0  & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
 1& 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}

Is this true? I don't know why I'm having so much trouble getting this! If somebody could walk me through this that would be great. Thank you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix#Examples

Comment: To be clear, is the convention that *you* follow where permutations are applied left-to-right?  Or is it right-to-left?  Both conventions sadly are in use and so this must be clarified before continuing.

Comment: I've tried both, and I don't think either give me this permutation matrix, unless I did something wrong....

Comment: Assuming permutations were applied right-to-left, it would have been $1\mapsto 1\mapsto 1\mapsto 2\mapsto 2,~2\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto 3\mapsto 1$ and so on and would have been in two-line notation $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&1&4&3\end{pmatrix}$.  If it were left-to-right we would have had $1\mapsto 3\mapsto 3\mapsto 2\mapsto 2$ and $2\mapsto 2\mapsto 1\mapsto 1\mapsto 1$ and so on...  It so happens that they both happen to give the same result but this is uncommon and a fluke.

Comment: Converting from a two-line notation to a permutation matrix is simply a matter of putting the corresponding entry in a row equal to $1$ in the corresponding column and $0$'s elsewhere in the row according to whether the index of the row maps to the index of the column according to the permutation.  That is... $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Hm... Thank you sir. Your calculations appear quite correct and yet they do not match the permutation matrix that I thought they should... I'll try to go see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume left-to-right multiplication and simplify the product of transpositions in three ways. This might help to better see what's going on.

**Cycle multiplication:**

\begin{align*}
\left(\left((13)(12)\right)(23)\right)(34)&=\left((132)(23)\right)(34)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=(12)(34)}
\end{align*}

**Two line notation:**

\begin{align*}
&\left(\left(
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\3&2&1&4\end{pmatrix}\circ
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&1&3&4\end{pmatrix}
\right)\circ
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&3&2&4\end{pmatrix}\right)\circ
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&2&4&3\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\3&1&2&4\end{pmatrix}
\circ
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&3&2&4\end{pmatrix}\right)\circ
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&2&4&3\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&1&3&4\end{pmatrix}\circ
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&2&4&3\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&1&4&3\end{pmatrix}}\\
\end{align*}

**Matrix notation:**

\begin{align*}
&\left(\left(\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=\left(\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}}
\end{align*}